# Set protection level to save sensitive in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I can't get SSIS to connect to SQL Server. I have a connection setup in Connection Managers but whenever I run the package I get login failed for user sa. I know this is because the the protection level is set to "Don't Save Sensitive". The problem is I don't want to encrypt anything but I do want it save the password. I do not care about security. I've put the password everywhere I can think of. It's in the dtsconfig file connection string, it's in a variable, it's in the connection manager window and the Test Connection button works. I just want it to save the password. Where is the option for "Save Sensitive"?

I don't understand the function of the Connection Manager if it does not save credentials. Why have a user name and password field at all? Why have a "Save my password" checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do this in the UI but you can do it if you edit the dtsx manually.

Look for `<DTS:ConnectionManager DTS:ConnectionString`. Under that you should find `<DTS:Password`. Set `Sensitve` to `0` and type in the password. At the end it should look like:

`<DTS:Password DTS:Name="Password" Sensitive="0">yourPasswordHere</DTS:Password>`